# How to display a property of a class in a MessageBox

Tags: c#, winforms, class

I've got school project I'm finishing up but for some extra points I have to use a class for something.  What I hoped to do was put a message box up right when I opened the program, using info contained in a class.

This is what I have right now

```
    public void Info()
    {
        string Hello = "Please remember that all information is confidential!";
    }
```

Then this is what I have on my forms Load event for the project

```
    private void frmCustomerInfo_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Greeting hello = new Greeting();
        MessageBox.Show(hello);
    }
```

Now obviously that didn't work, what must I do to have the info I want in a class then call it to the message box at form load? Thanks!

Comment: Suggested reading: **[Scope of Variables in C#](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-of-variables-in-c-sharp/)**  also **[Basic Concepts - Declarations in C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/basic-concepts#73-declarations)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't defined your Greeting class.   Your Info() is not a class, it is just method that defines a string, but doesn't do anything with it or return anything from it.

Create a Greeting class with a property that returns a string:

```
public class Greeting
{
    public string Info
    {
        get { return "Please remember that all information is confidential!"; }
    }
}
```

Then inside your forms class, in your Load event, instantiate the Greeting class and pass to the messagebox's Show method the Info property of your greeting instance:

```
private void frmCustomerInfo_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var greeting = new Greeting();
    MessageBox.Show(greeting.Info);
}
```

I think from reading your question this is what you're going after.  Also assuming this in winforms, based on the looks of your code.

Study up and keep at it!